# Assigning a string to a variable of type char in C

Tags: c, string, variables, char

i have used the code.

```
char *y;
y="hello world";
printf("%c",y);
```

it just shows something useless.
What mistake i am making.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change :

```
printf("%c",y);
```

to :

```
printf("%s",y);
```

as `%c` specifier indicates a `char`. To identify a string, you need the specifier `%s`.

Comment: Now its working thanks.

Comment: @Shantanuvidwans glad that I helped! You could accept an answer if your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 1):

To print a c-string use the `%s` format specifier in `printf`. What is happening now is that `y` evaluates to some address and then you are trying to print that address using `%c` which causes [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1):

It is [`undefined behaviour`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you have used wrong format specifier.

**C11 Standard: §7.21.6.1:**
**Paragraph 9:**

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.225) If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding coversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

So, use `%s` instead of `%c` for character string.